# Javascript - Output return value of an object method

Tags: javascript, object, methods, return

Newbie alert.  I'm new to JavaScript.  Love it so far.  I'm having a bit of a problem I hope someone can help me with:

Here's my script in a .js file:

```
function human(name, age, gender){
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.gender = gender;
  this.yearsToRetirement = function(){                  
          return 65 - this.age;

  };
}


var Steve = new human('Steve', 34, 'Male');
document.write(Steve.name + "  " + Steve.age + "  " + Steve.gender + Steve.yearsToRetirement);
```

But here's my browser output:

```
Steve 34 Malefunction (){ return 65 - this.age; }
```

As you may have guessed, I'm looking for there to be a "31" where we see `function (){ return 65 - this.age; }`

...What gives?

Any help is MUCH appreciated.

Comment: `yearsToRetirement` is a method of an object, so you have to call it with `Steve.yearsToRetirement()`

Answer (score 1):

As yearsToRetirement is a function you want to execute it. Try this

```
var Steve = new human('Steve', 34, 'Male');
document.write(Steve.name + " " + Steve.age + " " + Steve.gender + Steve.yearsToRetirement());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through `getter`. Then, `Steve.yearsToRetirement` works fine.

```js
function human(name, age, gender){
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.gender = gender;
  var _yearsToRetirement = 65 - this.age;
  Object.defineProperties(this, {
        yearsToRetirement: {
            get: function () {
                return 65 - this.age;
            },
            enumerable: true
        }
    });  
}


var Steve = new human('Steve', 34, 'Male');
document.write(Steve.name + "  " + Steve.age + "  " + Steve.gender + Steve.yearsToRetirement + "<br>");

Steve.age = 40;
document.write(Steve.name + "  " + Steve.age + "  " + Steve.gender + Steve.yearsToRetirement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `yearsToRetirement` as a function object here and not running it:

```
document.write(Steve.name + "  " + Steve.age + "  " + Steve.gender + Steve.yearsToRetirement);
```

Instead, you need to call the function, like this:

```
document.write(Steve.name + "  " + Steve.age + "  " + Steve.gender + Steve.yearsToRetirement());
```